# Tabs stop responding to clicks with API level lower than 22

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I'm using a tablayout with viewpager to swetch between different pages. This works fine when I compile with Android version 6.0 and target Android 5.1 (Lollipop) but I can't switch to different fragment by clicking the tabs when I target other versions of Android like KitKat or Ice Cream. 
What is the minimum version supported by the Support Library for using ViewPager?

In my app, I have the main layout setup as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@menu/toolbar" />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Bottom Tab menu -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Yourtime.NonSwipeableViewpager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
<!-- The Left Navigation Drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Inside the OnCreate methode of the MainActivity I have:

```
        viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);



        tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

The method to setup the viewpager:

```
        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
    {

        var adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        adapter.addFrag(new feedFragment(), "Home");
        adapter.addFrag(new MessageFragment(), "Inbox");
        adapter.addFrag(new UploadFragment(), "upload");
        adapter.addFrag(new NotificationFragment(), "Notifications");
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "Five");
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

Is it at all possible to use the ViewPager with other versions of Android?

**EDIT**

I'm using a NonSwipeable viewpager to disable swipe so I can only go to different views by clicking the tablayout buttons. Here's my NonSwipebleViewPager class:

```
    class NonSwipeableViewpager : ViewPager
{
    public NonSwipeableViewpager(Context context):base(context)
    {

    }

    public NonSwipeableViewpager(Context context,  Android.Util.IAttributeSet attr)
        : base(context, attr)
    {

    }

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the ViewPagerAdapter:

```
    class ViewPagerAdapter : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public List<V4Fragment> mFragmentList = new List<V4Fragment>();
    public List<String> mFragmentTitleLis = new List<string>();
    Context ctxt = null;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context ctxt, V4FragmentManager manager)
        : base(manager)
    {
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(V4FragmentManager manager) : base(manager) { }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList[position];;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mFragmentList.Count; }
    }

    public void addFrag(V4Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.Add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleLis.Add(title);
    }

    public void addFrag(V4Fragment fragment, String title, Bundle user)
    {
        fragment.Arguments = user;
        mFragmentList.Add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleLis.Add(title);
    }

    public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.String(mFragmentTitleLis[position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a build error occuring ? If so in which file and in which line ?

Comment: `ViewPager` support goes back to API 4. `TabLayout` and the design library are supported from API 7. So it should work everywhere from API 7 (Android 2.1). Can you better describe "but I can't switch to different fragment"? Are you getting a crash? Does tab layout update but view pager doesn't switch screen? Does nothing happen at all? Have you tried with a non-custom pager adapter?

Comment: I can't go to other pages associated with the TabLayout buttons. I'm using a NonSwipeable Viewpager that has the swipe feature desable so I have to click the tablayout buttons to go to other views. I can do this when I run the app with API 22 but it doesn't work with API 19

Comment: The App build fine and I'm not getting any error in the build.

Comment: Please also share the definition of ViewPagerAdapter class

Comment: @Sreeraj I have updated the OP with the code

Comment: Tablayout looks a bit messed up too with other APIs.

Comment: What is the baseClass of your activity ?

Comment: @Sreeraj The base class inherits from AppCompatActivity

Comment: I think the problem maybe with the emulator I'm running since the app works fine when I run it with API 22 emulator with the app targeted at API 15 but it doesn't work with API 19 emulator

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I realized TabLayout has a minsdk of 22, so it must be it, right? However, @EugenPechanec said above it's supported from API7 onward. Am I missing something? Ps: I'm a beginner.

Comment: @bernardo.g What do you mean by "TabLayout has a minsdk of 22"? Where do you get this information? TabLayout is part of support library. The support library v26.x.x has min sdk 14, the support library v25.x.x has min sdk 9.

Comment: @EugenPechanec If I go to the developer's page for tablayout and choose API 19 at the navigation drawer to the left, I get a warning ("this class requires API level 22.2.0 or higher"), and the content of the page is grayed out. At the top of the page, to the right, it also says "added in version 22.2.0". I'm using the support library version (there doesn't seem to be a 'regular' one, am I right?). Again, I'm a beginner. Thank you!   Ps: I don't get a Lint warning in Android Studio (my minsdk is actually 19), so that's more confusing.

Comment: @bernardo.g Oh, I see! It's a bit confusing but when you're browsing reference to support library it means that *what you're looking at was introduced in support library v22.2.0*. That's it. Browse at your compile SDK version to get more accurate results. Android Studio will warn you when you try using something that's not available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [example](http://blog.falafel.com/31-days-of-xamarin-android-day-23-tablayout/) of ViewPager synchronized with Tablayout (Android Support Design Library Widget). Try changing the Base Class of the Activity from AppCompatActivity to FragmentActivity.